# Individually Detecting elements that share the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs (.block). Each one should turn red, depending on if another div (.square) is located on top of it. So far, only one '.square' is being recognized (the first one listed in the markup), and it's turning all '.block's red instead of just the one it's on top of. Also, any tips on making this more DRY would be really appreciated.

Here's my code -

```
var squareWidth = $('.square').width();
var squareHeight = $('.square').height();
var squareLeft = $('.square').offset().left;
var squareTop = $('.square').offset().top;
var squareRight = squareLeft + squareWidth;
var squareBottom = squareTop + squareHeight;

$('.block').each(function() {

var blockWidth = $(this).width();
var blockHeight = $(this).height();
var blockLeft = $(this).offset().left;
var blockTop = $(this).offset().top;
var blockRight = blockLeft + blockWidth;
var blockBottom = blockTop + blockHeight;

if(squareLeft > blockLeft && squareRight < blockRight && squareTop > blockTop 
    && squareBottom < blockBottom) {

    $('.block').css('background', 'red');
}
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net//QmE98/

Comment: `$('.block').eq(0)` will give you the first `<div>`; `$('.block').eq(1)` the second, and so on.

Comment: For reference, I would replace the references to $('.square') in the first four lines by adding the line "var $square = $('square');" and then referencing $square instead of looking it up again in the DOM every time. I'd probably also create a jQuery object variable in the each function. This will be more efficient.

Comment: The issue here is that the offset() method only applies to the first item in the collection. This means that your squareLeft variable only applies to your first square. If you console.log your conditions in the jsfiddle then you will see that squareLeft > blockLeft is false for the second two squares because of that. As a result the entire condition returns false and your style is never added.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` to refer to the specific instance of `.block` that's being examined:

```
if(squareLeft > blockLeft && squareRight < blockRight && squareTop > blockTop 
    && squareBottom < blockBottom) {

    $(this).css('background', 'red');
}
```

To abstract your code a bit more, use CSS class toggling instead:

```
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
```

---

UPDATE: Because of the way your HTML is structured, we'll have to reference elements by index:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/QmE98/10

```
$('.block').each(function () {
    // deduct the quantity of .square elements
    var myIndex = $(this).index() - $('.square').size();

    var squareWidth = $('.square').eq(myIndex).width();
    var squareHeight = $('.square').eq(myIndex).height();
    var squareLeft = $('.square').eq(myIndex).offset().left;
    var squareTop = $('.square').eq(myIndex).offset().top;
    ...

    if (squareLeft > blockLeft && squareRight < blockRight && squareTop > blockTop && squareBottom < blockBottom) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

If, however, you can do some mild restructuring of your HTML, this is much better:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/QmE98/5

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"><div style="top: 30px; left: 30px" class="square"></div></div>
    <div class="block"><div style="top: 30px; left: 150px" class="square"></div></div>
    <div class="block"><div style="top: 30px; left: 320px" class="square"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Though this only takes care of the first instance of '.square'. The other two still aren't working.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Sorry, that's probably a little vague. Take a look at the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net//QmE98/ I have three divs - each of them has a div named 'square' sitting on top of it. With your solution the first 'square' is detected and the div below it turns red. The other two divs named 'square' aren't detected and the divs below it aren't turning red. Thanks for your help!

Comment: They're all red for me in Chrome, IE10 & Firefox on Win7. If I comment out the operative statement and run it, they're dark gray.

Comment: They're all red because, in my original code the first div named 'square' turns them all red - instead of just changing the one it's sitting on. Changing $('.block') to $(this) - as per your suggestion - fixes this issue, though the other two '.squares' still don't change the color of the divs they're sitting on.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you hadn't updated the JS. Because of the way you've laid out your HTML, we'll have to get the index of each `.block` and reference its `.square`. Is your HTML set in stone?

Comment: If you can modify your HTML, this would be far simpler than using element indices: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/QmE98/5

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Yeah, unfortunately I have to make this work without making the '.squares' children of the '.blocks'.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmE98/2/)

Working.  Changed a few things -

1. Put the square class divs inside their corresponding block divs.
2. Moved the square functions into the loop, because otherwise they will be static to the last square.
3. Added a children fucntion to apply only to the square class under the current block.
4. Added (this) in the final line as shown

var squareWidth = $('.square').width();
        var squareHeight = $('.square').height();

```
$('.block').each(function() {
    var squareLeft = $(this).children('.square').offset().left;
    var squareTop = $(this).children('.square').offset().top;
    var squareRight = squareLeft + squareWidth;
    var squareBottom = squareTop + squareHeight;
    var blockWidth = $(this).width();
    var blockHeight = $(this).height();
    var blockLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    var blockTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var blockRight = blockLeft + blockWidth;
    var blockBottom = blockTop + blockHeight;

    if(squareLeft > blockLeft && squareRight < blockRight && squareTop > blockTop && squareBottom < blockBottom) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah crap, here's the rub though - this actually needs to work without the '.square' divs being children of the '.block' divs.

Comment: Alright - reset the square classes outside and ran an each loop through them, stored the variables in an array, and then used the squares arrays in the block loop to do the same thing.           [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmE98/11/)

Comment: Thanks so much! If you would allow me to waste even more of your time - is it possible to make it so that any one '.square' could turn any one '.block' red?

Comment: You'd have to modify the block loop to have each block check each square within the square array.  So, Block 1 checks each square in the square array, and if any of them are hits, then it turns red.  Then Block 2 checks them all, then Block 3, and so on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QmE98/13/ <- Updated.  I put numbers in the squares to show what's going on.